# Can the following method be used to generate a random invertible matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I'm trying to come up with a method to generate a random inverbile matrix. This is my guess.

Assume $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, such that the $LU$ decomposition can be applied. Therefore we'll have

$$
\begin{array}{l}
A = LU \\
(L)_{ij} = \begin{cases} 
0 & if \; i<j \\
1 & if \; i = j \\
l_{ij} \in \mathbb{R} &if\;i>j
\end{cases} \\
(U)_{ij} = \begin{cases} 
u_{ij} \in \mathbb{R} & if \; i < j \\
u_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}-\left\{ 0 \right\} & if \; i = j \\
0 &if\;i>j
\end{cases}
\end{array},
$$
therefore I need to generate all the $l_{ij},u_{ij}$ according to the constraints above. If those constraints are met then

$$
det(A) = det(L)det(U) = det(U) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}u_{ii}
$$

I guess this method might be valid, however I don't think that the distrubution of $A$ will be uniform across $R \subset \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. For example if $l_{11}$ and $u_{11}$ are uniformly distributed in some compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then the distribution of $a_{11}$ won't be uniform.

Is the method valid? I think this can be easily implemented on a computer. Are there methods well know in literature for this?

Comment: Assuming you restrict yourself to some bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, you can just as easily draw uniformly distributed matrices from that subset and then reject the non-invertible ones. The distribution will actually still be uniform, because the non-invertible matrices have Lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: @Ian that "easily" puzzles me, can you give a method or a reference?

Comment: Also, I don't know why you are taking the diagonal elements of $U$ to be positive while forcing the diagonal elements of $L$ to also be positive.

Comment: @Ian mistake for the diagonal, I meant $\mathbb{R} - \left\{ 0 \right\}$

Comment: I am saying that if you sample each $a_{ij}$ independently and uniformly from some fixed bounded interval $I$, with probability $1$ the matrix you get will be invertible, so you can produce invertible matrices "uniformly" in this way through rejection sampling. The distribution is indeed uniform in the sense of the Lebesgue measure because you've only excised a null set.

Comment: How would you perform the rejection? Would you apply gauss jordan and if you get a singular matrix you would then reject?

Comment: Sure. There are also other ways to check for invertibility.

Comment: @Ian Although that's true, it seems very inefficient practically compared to an algorithm to generate an invertible matrix directly (assuming there is such an efficient method).

Comment: @naslundx Depends on how you want the distribution to look. If you want it to be uniform in the underlying space, then this is probably your best bet. If you just want something with some nontrivial statistics, then something like a random LU factorization is perhaps better.

Comment: It is inefficient, especially for large matrices. But I understand the method.

Comment: @user8469759 It's technically inefficient, but it will almost never fail (because singular matrices have Lebesgue measure zero), so depending on what you are doing you could just decline to check and then throw an exception when it fails (at which point you just call the generator again). This assumes you have the freedom to write both the caller and the callee...but now we're getting into software issues.

Comment: @Ian In your method also ill conditioned matrices are quite likely to be generated.

Comment: If you want control on condition numbers then you should be more careful with a method like a random LU factorization, too. Your question is generally ill-posed since you're not saying what a "good" method is.

Comment: I think my case is easier to control honestly... which still is a proposal because I haven't seen algorithms that perform the task.

Comment: @Ian I'm commenting on your proposal, simple as that.

Comment: There is any number of methods which will allow you to generate non-singular matrices cheaply and give you control over the spectrum, the eigenvectors, the condition number, or give you an easy inverse. This is exceeding useful when testing numerical routines. Having the entries independent and uniformly distributed is something which I have never needed. You should elaborate on what you need and which application you have in mind.

Comment: I've just implemented some linear algebra routines that I need to test against some software or library I know works for sure. Therefore I'd just set up some random cases and compare them, especially high dimension of the matrices. In case they are corrett I need to compare the speed of what I've implemented against the library I'll use for validating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some possibilities.

A Householder reflector 
$$ Q = I - vv^T, \quad v \in \mathbb{R}^n, \quad v^Tv = 2$$
is an orthogonal matrix. In particular, $Q$ is nonsingular with condition number $1$. This option gives you a cheap inverse.

If $V$ is orthogonal and $\Lambda$ is real and diagonal, then
$$ A = V \Lambda V^T$$
is symmetric. If $\Lambda > 0$, then $A$ is symmetric positive definite and $A$ has an $LU$ decomposition. The inverse is simple and you have control over the condition number.

If the matrices $\{B_i\}_{i=1}^m$ are block diagonal, then their product $B = B_1B_2\dots B_m$ is banded. This is true in general, even when the block structures are not identical. If the matrices $B_i$ are nonsingular, then the matrix $B^{-1}$ is also banded. This gives you an cheap inverse.

If $Q$ is orthogonal and $S$ is quasi-upper-triangular, with either 1 by 1 or 2 by 2 blocks on the main diagonal, then 
$$ A = Q S Q^T $$
is a general dense matrix, where you have control over the (possibly) complex spectrum.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that essentially your approach is similar to mine? Namely build a non singular matrix through factoring?  Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes. You have no control over the numerical properties of your matrix. When you are unlucky our matrix will be so ill-conditioned, that no routine can produce meaningful results. You will have no way of knowing if your code works or not. If you have control over the condition number, then you can tell if your computed solutions are as accurate as you have a right to expect or if your implementation still contains a nefarious error which allows for semi-accurate results, which are worse than they should be.